Supply Maven arguments separately in GitHub workflow
Given a working workflow file with a Maven build step such as this:
      steps:
      - name: verify
        run: mvn --show-version --no-transfer-progress --update-snapshots --fail-at-end --batch-mode -Dstyle.color=always verify

As I need to add additional goals to the invocation, I would prefer to have the other arguments grouped somewhere else – something like this:
      steps:
      - name: verify
        with:
          args:
            --show-version
            --no-transfer-progress
            --update-snapshots
            --fail-at-end
            --batch-mode
            -Dstyle.color=always
        run: mvn verify

Unfortunately that fails with
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/ci.yml (Line: 48, Col: 9): Unexpected value 'run' .github/workflows/ci.yml (Line: 39, Col: 9): Required property is missing: uses


You can't just make up semantics, no - a run: step doesn't have with:. You can split the script onto multiple lines with YAML's various multiline string syntax forms.

Following jonrsharpe's reminder regarding YAML features i'm now using the folded block scalar style with strip folding to define environment variables such as:
env:
  MAVEN_OPTS: '-Dstyle.color=always'
  MAVEN_SWITCHES: >-
    --show-version
    --no-transfer-progress
    --update-snapshots
    --fail-at-end
    --batch-mode

at the top of the workflow YAML, which enables to refactor the Maven invocation to:
    # …
      steps:
      - name: verify
        run: mvn ${{ env.MAVEN_SWITCHES }} verify

NB: MAVEN_OPTS is not exploded in the run command as it's a common Maven environment variable that is applied automatically.
